# I do something wrong with Azure Offline Sync

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I think I do something wrong with offline update between Xamarin.form and Azure.
I use Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.2. All the initial sync work good. The problem I face is when I try to update an item locally then sync to the server. For my test, I change the Statut field of an Appel (french program;-)) object then call UpadteAsync (locally update) then I call the main syncAppelsAsync (remotely update)

```html
public async Task UpdateAppelAsync(Appel appel)
{
  await _appelsTable.UpdateAsync(appel);            
  await SyncAppelsAsync();                
}
```

Then main SyncAppelsAsync:

```html
public async Task SyncAppelsAsync()
{
    await _authenticationService.SingIn();  


    ReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors = null;

    try
    {
        await _appelsTable.PullAsync("allAppels", _appelsTable.CreateQuery());
    }
    catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
    {
        if (exc.PushResult != null)
        {
            syncErrors = exc.PushResult.Errors;
        }
    }

    //Simple error/ conflict handling.
    bool reSync = false;
    if (syncErrors != null)
    {
        foreach (var error in syncErrors)
        {
            if (error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Update && error.Result != null)
            {
                StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Champs en problème: Local VS Server" + Environment.NewLine);
                List<SyncConflic> conflits = JSonCompare.FindConflicObjects(error.Item, error.Result);
                foreach (SyncConflic conflit in conflits)
                {
                    if (conflit.key != "id" && conflit.key != "version" && conflit.key != "updatedAt" & conflit.key != "createdAt")
                    {
                        switch (conflit.key)
                        {
                            case "statutId":
                                Statut StatLoc = await this.GetStatutByIdAsync(conflit.local);
                                Statut StatRem = await this.GetStatutByIdAsync(conflit.remote);
                                message.Append(conflit.key + ":" + StatLoc.nom + " <> " + StatRem.nom + Environment.NewLine);
                                break;
                            default:
                                message.Append(conflit.key + ":" + conflit.local + " <> " + conflit.remote + Environment.NewLine);
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                }

                message.Append("Quelle version voulez-vous conserver?" + Environment.NewLine);
                if(await _extDialogService.ShowMessage(message.ToString(),"Conflit de MAJ d'un Appel", "Serveur", "Local",null))
                {
                    // Revert to server's copy
                    await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(error.Result);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Force local item to server
                    error.Item["version"] = error.Result["version"];
                    await error.UpdateOperationAsync(error.Item);
                    reSync = true;
                }



            }
            else
            {
                // Discard local change
                await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
                ErrorHandling.LogError("Error executing sync operation. Item: " + error.TableName + " (" + error.Item["id"] + "). Operation discarded.");
            }


        }
    }
    if(reSync)
    {
        await SyncAppelsAsync();
    }
}
```

When I call the SyncAppelsAsync, the PullAsync will do a Push if needed. The problem I got:

1. Change an Appel Statut field
2. Call the UpdateAPpelAsync (local save OK in IOS DB)
3. Call the SyncAppelsAsync (remote Azure SQL change OK)
4. Change the statut field again
5. Call the UpdateAPpelAsync (local save OK in IOS DB)
6. Call the SyncAppelsAsync --> Conflic detected, so my conflict resolution start and ask me to choose between server or local data. Why a conflict is detected on Version and Statut field? The 2 update was made from the IOS client without any other system changing it on the Azure SQL...

To update without Conflic I need to:

1. Change an Appel Statut field
2. Call the UpdateAPpelAsync (local save OK in IOS DB)
3. Call the SyncAppelsAsync (remote Azure SQL change OK)
4. **Call the SyncAppelsAsync AGAIN (I do it on my list view with a pull to refresh)**
5. Change the statut field again
6. Call the UpdateAPpelAsync (local save OK in IOS DB)
7. Call the SyncAppelsAsync (no conflict, update successful)

What did I do wrong?

EDIT2------
I found somthing wierd with the version # between 2 PATCH operation

1. After updating the item and synch for the first time with PullAsync(). I see the PATCH operation sending the modified item with version AAAAAJyU= (we see the version number in the headers cache instruction If-Match="AAAAAJyU=")
2. Then the GET (second part of the pullAsync) start and return the object with new version #AAAAAJyg=
3. When I do the second update, PullAsync() send the correct modified item (I can see the change in the JSON) but in the If-Match instruction, the old AAAAAJyU version number is send. So the server expected to receive AAAAAJyg= return HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed.

So something is not write back in the localDB. after PullAsync is complete...

Comment: What backend are you using (C# or Node.js)? One potential cause of this symptom is if your update code on the server is not sending back the updated record to the phone in the response body for the PATCH request.

Comment: Also I'd like to see your client-side model object for the Appel.

Comment: You are using the Implicit Pushes when executing the pull operation for synchronizing between your local cache and the remote table. AFAIK, the common processing would execute `await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();await table.PullAsync();`.

Comment: Just as Eric Hedstrom commented, I would recommend you trace the network when executing step3, and compare the record between your local side and the remote table to narrow this issue. Moreover, you could provide your custom logging message for us to troubleshoot this issue. Moreover, you could follow [updating-the-sync-tables](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#updating-the-sync-tables) and [Handling Conflict Resolution](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#handling-conflict-resolution).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I update my question with more info. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still lost! ;-)  @Bruce Chen

Comment: I found somthing wierd with the version # between 2 PATCH operation. See the Edit2 in the main post.

Comment: Hi Pierre. Were you able to ever solve the issue? I am facing the same issue on my Xamarin Forms app as well.

Comment: No, the project has beeen put in hold. So I do not work on that anymore.